# "OnCompleted" does not work for useQuery when using "refetchQueries" in useMutation, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

When using useMutation, I add refetchQueries to get the modified data.

```
let [saveTemplate, { loading}] = useMutation(gql`
  ${templateFragment}
  mutation saveTemplate ($template:saveTemplateTemplatesType!,$token:String!){
    saveTemplate(template:$template,token:$token){
    ...template
    }
  }
  `,{refetchQueries:["getUserData"],onError:()=>{message.warn("error")},onCompleted:()=>{console.log("success")}});
```

A mutation request is made to the server. The data is returned, but the onCompleted of useQueries does not work.

```
let { loading } = useQuery(
    gql`
      ${templateFragment}
      query getUserData($userToken: String) {
        getUsersData(userToken: $userToken) {
          templates {
            ...template
          }
          token
        }
      }
    `,
    {
      variables: {
        userToken: userToken ? userToken.replace(/"/g, ``) : null,
      },
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        props.isAuthAC(
          true,
          data.getUsersData.templates,
          data.getUsersData.token
        );
      },
      onError: () => console.log("err"),
    }
  );
```

Comment: open an issue on github ... but there is no reason to duplicate data from apollo cache to some other state (redux?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution on github. you need to add to useQuery: notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true.

```
  let { loading } = useQuery(
    gql`
      ${templateFragment}
      query getUserData($userToken: String) {
        getUsersData(userToken: $userToken) {
          templates {
            ...template
          }
          token
        }
      }
    `,
    {
      variables: {
        userToken: userToken ? userToken.replace(/"/g, ``) : null,
      },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        props.isAuthAC(
          true,
          data.getUsersData.templates,
          data.getUsersData.token
        );
      },
      onError: () => console.log("err"),
    }
  );
```